# Default method to suppress "Connection to xxx closed." when use ssh -t?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

When use ssh to login to a remote pc to execute a command, everything looks fine, but it will give an additional line at the end of output `Connection to 10.192.244.104 closed`:

```
$ ssh -t 10.192.244.104 -- pwd
/root
Connection to 10.192.244.104 closed.
```

Does ssh has any option to suppress that line? Or I have to remove it with my own program after called that `ssh -t`? You know if I don't use `-t`, that line won't be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is sent to stderr.

```
ssh -t 10.192.244.104 -- pwd 2>/dev/null
```